# frequency table doesn't work for subsets

Tags: r, subset, dummy-variable

I have a dataset and defined different subsets in order to look on frequencies for dummy variables.

```
copying <- subset (reversals, Task =='copy')
writing <- subset (reversals, Task =='write')
```

edit: My data looks like this:

```
ID   task  X1  X2  X3  X4
 1   copy   0   1   0   0
 1   write  1   0   0   1
 2   copy   0   1   1   0
 2   write  1   1   1   0
 3   copy   0   1   0   0
 3   write  0   0   0   1
```

I ran this code on the complete dataset and the subsets:

```
hfgk.reversals0 <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(reversals[,11:26], table)))
hfgk.reversals0$Sum <- rowSums(hfgk.reversals0)
hfgk.reversals <- data.frame(hfgk.reversals0)
hfgk.reversals

hfgk.reversals0.copying <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(copying[,11:26], table)))
hfgk.reversals0.copying$Sum <- rowSums(hfgk.reversals0.copying)
hfgk.reversals.copying <- data.frame(hfgk.reversals0.copying)
hfgk.reversals.copying
```

For the complete dataset I got a beautiful table as result:

```
    X0  X1  Sum
X1  1600  16  1616
X2  1614  2   1616
```

but not for the subset:

```
X1 X10 X12 X14 X15 X16 X18 X2 X3 X4 X44 X5 X6 X7 X9 X17
 1 369, 1 370 370 370     370 370 370 366, 4 370 370 369, 1 368, 2 352, 18 370 366, 4 370
```

The correct information is also contained, but somehow structured differently. 
While for the first table, variable are described like: X0: int 1600 1614, it looks like this for the subset: $ X1: 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 369 1 - attr(*,dimnames) = list of 1 ...$: chr "0" "1"

I really appreciate any help, because I don't really see through the underlying mechanism.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using bracket subsetting?

```
copying <- reversals[reversals$Task =='copy',]
writing <- reversals[reversals$Task =='write',]
```

You didn't include any reproducible data, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Thank you!Yes and the result is the same. Sorry for not providing data. Can you tell me, how to upload a datafile?

Comment: What file type is your dataset? Do you mean to upload here, or read it into R?

Comment: It's a .txt, but of course I could also export it into another format. I meant, how can I provide the reproducible data to you

Comment: The same way you included the table showing the successful summary output, but add a few extra observations to show a representative sample of your data.